# в чём различие между категорией и видом глагола?

Tags: морфология

Русский глагол в сопоставлении с чешским — общая характеристика части речи и наличие главных грамматических категорий; глагольные формы и их классификация; система спряжения русских глаголов и характеристика продуктивных и непродуктивных глаголов; основные отличия русского спряжения от чешского.

Comment: Не думаю, что этот вопрос найдет здесь ответ. Во-первых, это чешский язык, не уверен, что есть специалисты, да и не по теме. Во-вторых,  то не вопрос, а целая тема, здесь конкретные вещи обуждаются. На вопрос, вынесенный в заголовок я попробую ответить - в меру своего незнания. Но не больше.

Comment: спасибо за Ваш комментарий! для меня самое главное узнать, в чём различие между категорией и видом глагола в русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

"Категория" в общей грамматике - общее название квалифицирующих признаков, системных элементов, по которым осуществляется грамматический разбор. Это понятийное определение, научное определение весьма сложно.

Вот из вики:
Граммати́ческая катего́рия — замкнутая система взаимоисключающих и противопоставленных друг другу грамматических значений (граммем), задающая разбиение обширной совокупности словоформ (или небольшого набора высокочастотных словоформ с абстрактным типом значения) на непересекающиеся классы, различие между которыми существенно сказывается на степени грамматической правильности текста.

У русского глагола есть **категории** лица, вида, залога и т.д. 
Таким образом **вид** - всего лишь одна из **категорий**. Она характеризует законченность действия к некоторому моменту, противопоставляя действию продолжающемуся.

Что там в чешском - не знаю. Понимаю письменный на уровне интуиции процентов на 30%, как и большинство славянских, не думаю, что этого достаточно для суждений.  )))

А где это такие вопросы на экзаменах задают?

Comment: behemothus, спасибо Вам большое за ответ! :) Такие вопросы задают на первом курсе в чешском университете, у нас их, в общей сложности, 10, а кое-кто как всегда поздно сел готовиться к экзамену и запутался. :)

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить только ссылки, может, понадобятся.

http://www.philol.msu.ru/~ruslang/pdfs/petrukhina-ev_6sblijzenie_i_peresechenie_klassov_glagolov.pdf

https://is.muni.cz/th/181126/ff_b/Razlicnoe_upotreblenije_vidov_v_cesskom_i_russkom_jazykach.pdf

http://cz-online.ru/grammatika/

http://subscribe.ru/archive/job.lang.czech/200701/24164732.html

http://www.twirpx.com/file/963923/